# How to make exposed wire safe

Tags: electrical

I live in Canada, and recently removed an old dishwasher. There was a power cord that I snipped, and was wondering how I could make it safe? Could this be a potential fire hazard if left as is? [image]

Comment: Leave the breaker off and label it, you did turn off the breaker before cutting?   Strip the the wires some and put wire nut on each wire.

Comment: If permanently abandoning the wire, remove the other end from the breaker and remove all accessible parts of the wire. If you're going to use the wire in the future, @crip659 has made a comment that should be an answer ;^) Generally, "snipping" is not the way to deal with wires/cables you might ever want to use again, because you run out of length after a few go-rounds. Removing them from the wiring terminals on the device is less prone to making you irritated with the guy who left you 2" short when you wire the next thing.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  Both comments together would make a proper answer.  If you want can add my comment to make the answer.

Comment: @crip659 - you were first, and I certainly don't have any particular need (or use) for more points at this point, so feel free to swipe my comment and implement the idea that direction.

Comment: Either of you could tag it "community wiki" if neither feels entitled to the points or credit... :)

Comment: @crip659 I can't seem to find the dishwasher on the breaker.. it appears to be connected to the kitchen breaker as when I turn off the kitchen lights.. the dishwasher went out as well.

Comment: You never want to leave bare copper conductors(hot and neutral/black and white) where someone can touch them.  Guess what happens when someone places their hand/arm/tongue on that cable.  Best is to remove that cable from the circuit at panel or in your case a junction box.  Second best is to strip wires and place wire nuts on the ends.  Do all with power off.

Comment: Got lucky that did not burn your cutters and a nice arc? Or did you turn the power off if power off you know where the breaker is wire nut at least the hot if you can’t find the other end or put tape on it, believe it or not as my last job I found multiple hot 277v conductors just cut off no tape on the ends nothing it was outside under a metal roof I was glad I checked before messing with them